# How to modify a web application when the solution file is not preseent?

Tags: asp.net

I have been asked to modify an ASP.NET 3.5 web application.  The solution file does not appear to be present on the web server, but there is a DLL.  Is it possible to modify the solution by "reverse engineering" the DLL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be possible. The [4GuysFromRolla](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020103545/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/080404-1.aspx) have an article about it.

The real question, however, is, if you really want to do this. It takes loads of time to do this. I´d try to get the real source xD

Answer (score 0):

The web server is where the running application is stored. The sources are stored elsewhere. Find out where.

Comment: The .sln file appears to be in wwwroot, but when I open it locally, many assets are excluded.  Not sure if this is the true source or not.

Comment: Which assets are missing? People almost never leave the source in wwwroot. Look elsewhere.

Comment: I'm the 3rd person to work on this site.  The server is riddled with all sorts of backup files from previous people's work.